# Django rest framework legacy DB foreign keys appearing as Null on API

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am using django connected to a legacy mysql DB. So i used inspectdb to get the DB tables. There are 2 models that I am using:

```
class ScCustomerTypes(models.Model):
    customer_type_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    customer_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'sc_customer_types'


class ScCustomers(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    identification_number = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    customer_type = models.ForeignKey('ScCustomerTypes', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='customer_types2customers', to_field='customer_type_id')
    customer_names = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'sc_customers'
```

Using the above I made the below serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from allDBModels.models import ScCustomers, ScCustomerTypes
from employees.serializers import AllEmployeeSerializer

class AllCustomerTypesSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ScCustomerTypes
        fields = ('customer_type',)

class AllCustomerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    customer_type_id = AllCustomerTypesSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = ScCustomers
        fields = ('customer_id', 'customer_type_id', 'customer_names', 'phone_number', 'identification_number', 'location', 'created_by', 'created_at', 'updated_by', 'updated_at',)
```

Issue now is when i pull the api it returns as such:

```
{
        "customer_id": "ICXY38ZP",
        "customer_type_id": {
            "customer_type": null
        },
        "customer_names": "Test xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "phone_number": "2547xxxxxxx",
        "identification_number": "yyyyyyyyyy",
        "location": null,
        "created_by": "3b1e3f79",
        "created_at": "2020-10-20T13:58:21Z",
        "updated_by": null,
        "updated_at": null
    },
```

The issue is that its not returning the customer_type. What could be the issue here? I tested this with a db in sqlite with tables created by models and it works perfectly. So what is the issue

Comment: May be `customer_type` is `null` as your db allow it

Comment: nope its not null every customer has a customer type. That table has over 5000 customers and they are null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the serializers.StringRelatedField method as bellow.
Let's start by adding a def **str** function to your model class

```
class ScCustomerTypes(models.Model):
customer_type_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
customer_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'sc_customer_types'
def __str__(self):
    return '%s' %(self.customer_type) #returns a string prop when the model is queried
```

Hereafter let as create a property on your AllCustomerSerializer class.

```
class AllCustomerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
#customer_type_id = AllCustomerTypesSerializer()
_customer_type = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True, source='customer_type') #source is the name of the related field in the ScCustomers model class.
class Meta:
    model = ScCustomers
    fields = ('_customer_type', 'customer_names',)#remember to include the StringRelatedField in this tuple.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
class AllCustomerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    customer_type_id = AllCustomerTypesSerializer(source='customer_type')

    class Meta:
        model = ScCustomers
        fields = ('customer_id', 'customer_type_id', 'customer_names', 'phone_number', 'identification_number', 'location', 'created_by', 'created_at', 'updated_by', 'updated_at',)
```

If this will not work then this value must be a null value

Comment: Tried that it just keeps loading and no response. I did a DB query and you can see the customer type clearly. I also pulled the serializer into a view of its own and it does return the customer types. I think the issue here must foreign keys are not mapping to the table accurately from djangos side because in DB its okay